How to List All Transformations in an Informatica Data Integration Project Using an API?
I'm new to Informatica and I'm trying to list all the transformations present in an Informatica Data Integration project using an API.
My goal is to get the following structure:
ProjectName -> FolderName (mappings) -> Transformations

Example:
ProjectA -> Mapping_task -> mt_a -> backend

I tried using the mttask API, but it didn't work for me. Is there any API available that provides detailed lineage of transformations? Alternatively, are there other methods to achieve this?
Thanks in advance for your help!
